# Display multi-line text and image on the same row in CSS

Tags: html, css

How do you do that? For example, if my text is too long, it should auto-wrap but the entire text should still be on the same row as the image. Something like:

```
+------+
|image | text, text, text
|      | and more text
+------+
```

Is it possible? I tried:

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/100" /><span style = "display:inline">text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text and more text</span>
```

But all it does is to wrap the exceeding text to the row below both the image and the text.

Thanks! Sorry if my explanation is not clear, as I cannot post images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding `float:left` to the elements ( both img and text ).

Code:

```
<img style="float:left" src = "image.png" />
<span style = "float:left">text, text, text and more text</span>
```

Comment: although this will work, inline css isn't recommended

Comment: Removed the display:inline.

Comment: For some strange reason, that didn't work. However, by putting float:left on my img and totally removing the span (just putting the text directly) works. Anyway, thanks!